# Create a procedure to insert multiple values into a table, using a single variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Goal**: To create a procedure to insert multiple values into a table, using a single variable.

Challenge: Instead of making multiple hits in the same table, I have created a single variable (`@SQL`) and stored multiple columns (`fm_id` and `shdl_id` ) results in it but I am unable to use this single variable in the insert statement.

**Code**:

```
create proc abc
(
@org_id numeric(10,0),
@shdl_id numeric(10,0),
@usr_id numeric(10,0),
@tst_id numeric(10,0)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
 DECLARE @SQL NUMERIC(10);
 SET @SQL= (SELECT fm_id,@shdl_id FROM [dbo].[students] WHERE ORG_ID=@org_id AND shdl_id=@shdl_id AND TST_ID=@tst_id)

 INSERT INTO [USER]
 SELECT org_id,@usr_id,TST_ID,login_name,@SQL FROM [students] WHERE ORG_ID=@org_id AND shdl_id=@shdl_id AND TST_ID=@tst_id

 END
 GO
```

**Error** :

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure abc, Line 14 [Batch Start Line
>   94] Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

[image: Error]

Comment: Does your user table have 5 columns?

Comment: A variable can only hold one value, unless the variable is a TABLE itself. Also, "blind" inserts are up there (in terms of badness) as `SELECT *`.

Comment: Actually, why do you even need to use `@SQL`? The query you are trying to populate it with is almost the same as the one used for the insert. Why not just `INSERT ... SELECT org_id, @usr_id, TST_ID, login_name, fm_id, @shdlid FROM ...`?

Comment: Please avoid using images for data/errors/code. Instead format the text directly in and your question will be much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your SELECT return only one value into the variable. There's no point selecting `@shdl_id` because you already know it?

```
 DECLARE @pFMID NUMERIC(10);
 SELECT @pFMID = MAX(fm_id) FROM [dbo].[students] WHERE ORG_ID=@org_id AND shdl_id=@shdl_id AND TST_ID=@tst_id);
```

Then because you're not inserting a value into every column in the user table you need to explicitly state which columns to fill. Replace x1..x5 below with real column names (in the order the SELECT has them)

```
 INSERT INTO [USER](x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
 --                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 --           REPLACE THESE WITH REAL NAME

 SELECT org_id,@usr_id,TST_ID,login_name,@pFMID FROM [students] WHERE ORG_ID=@org_id AND shdl_id=@shdl_id AND TST_ID=@tst_id

 END
 GO
```

And as Uueerdo pointed out, this first query is a bit of a waste of time, we can write this:

```
create proc abc
(
...
)
AS
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO [USER](x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
 SELECT org_id,@usr_id,TST_ID,login_name,fm_id FROM [students] WHERE ORG_ID=@org_id AND shdl_id=@shdl_id AND TST_ID=@tst_id
 --                                      ^^^^^
 --                                      look!
```

You can only get away with leaving the column list off an INSERT if you're inserting the same number of columns the table has:

```
CREATE TABLE x(col1 INT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO x VALUES (1,2)     -- works 
INSERT INTO x VALUES (1)       -- fails: which column should have the 1?
INSERT INTO x(col1) VALUES (1) -- works: col1 shall have the 1
```